# Why is it called dynamic binding?

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic, virtual, language-lawyer

We use virtual to achieve **dynamic binding** in **Cpp** i.e. to decide at runtime which function has to be called based on the actual object created rather than the reference or the pointer variable.

```
class A
{
 int a;
public:
 virtual void show();
};

void A::show() { cout<<a<<endl; }

class B:public A
{
 int b;
public:
 void show() { cout<<b<<endl; }
};

class C:public A
{
 int c;
public:
 void show() { cout<<c<<endl; }
};
```

Assume, `someFunction(A& aref)`. It can take an object of type `B` or `C` or `A`

<sub>**Note:** Assuming values of data members are set</sub>

I mean the path is defined (It can be A or B or C). It isn't exactly `run time dependent` [like asking user to enter age and the user enters some word or some other datatype].

But **why is this called** as `run time binding`? 
The compiler does make a check beforehand if the object to be assigned will be compatible 
or no.

Is the terminology used to indicate that there is no strict association of the reference variable with a particular type of object and it is decided at run-time. 
Is there more to this ?

Comment: It's dynamic because virtual method calls cannot be fully resolved at compile-time (when called via a pointer or reference); they can only be resolved to a particular vtable pointer.  Which method that pointer will point to is not known at compile-time.

Comment: *"I mean the path is defined (It can be A or B or C)."* It could also be a completely different type, if you are building a library. In this case consumers of your library can define their own types, and so the set of all types that derive from A cannot possibly be known when you compile your library.

Comment: @cdhowie. Ok. I didnt consider about it being a library and having derived classes in the future. Thanks for steering in the right direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual methods create a **[virtual table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)** in the object which is used to call the methods.

The right method is looked up at runtime.

The case where it's most evident, is if you'd have a list of the base class, which contains  different kinds of objects:

```
std::list<A*> myList = new std::list<A*>();
myList.push_back(new A());
myList.push_back(new B());
myList.push_back(new C());

for (A* a : myList)
{
    a->show();
}
```

In this little example all the objects are of different types, the compiler sees them all as **A** object (there's a variable of type **A** calling **show()**), but still the right method is called.

Answer (score 2):

A compiler cannot always determine the exact type of a variable. When you work with pointers of a base class, they can be of any derived type. The derived type of a base class pointer can, in general, only be resolved at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

There can be additional subtypes in other translation units. Furthermore, even if you consider all translation units that are compiled in one batch, dynamic linking can introduce new subtypes years after the source code and the compiler which could compile it was eaten by a grue. It really is decided at run time: The code generated to call a `virtual` method fetches a function pointer from (a pointer in) the object, so it's a run-time value and may take on any value at all.

Comment: Ok, so it is based on the function pointer present in the object. That makes it runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to use a class in runtime dependent context to actually see late binding.

Consider something like this:

```
// foo.hpp
struct A {
virtual void show();
virtual ~A();
};
struct B : A {
  void show();
};
A* get_stuff(std::string x);

// the implementation is in foo.cpp and doesn't interest us here


// main.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
int main()
{
  std::string input;
  // .. read stuff from the user
  A* a = get_stuff(input);
  a->show(); // how would the compiler know which show is being called?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between static binding and dynamic binding is that static binding is defined at compile-time - which means that no matter what type of object, it will always call the same member function from whatever class the compiler determines is right, and dynamic binding (or runtime binding) is defined when the code is running. Meaning that the compiler has generated code that will "pick" the corresponding function as the code is being executed, based on what class it belongs to.

The object obviously needs to be COMPATIBLE, but the compiler doesn't have to know EXACTLY which class the object is during the compilation. Imagine that we have a program that can read a "shape, centre point and size" from a file, where size is just a "1-5" for extra small to extra large, and a function that can create an object of the class `square`, `circle` or `triangle`. Now feed it this:

```
Square 300, 300, 5
Circle 120, 300, 2
Circle 240, 300, 2
Triangle 300, 300, 1
```

Of course, the compiler won't know if you want to make a square, circle or triangle, or what order they come in. And the virtual "draw" function for each of the shapes is obviously different.

That may (if coordinates match up) draw something that sort of looks like a face (well, two eyes and a nose in a square at least).